# Show a part of image but with full width

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image but only a part of it and with a full (100% width), with no overflow

This is my code and it doesn't works:

```css
.intro_sea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 101%;
  clip-path: inset(30% 50% 0 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<img class="intro_sea" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161357.png" alt="huh" />
<img class="intro_sea" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161403.png" />
<img class="intro_sea" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161409.png" />
```

Sorry for the messy code, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Have you thought about using multipple CSS `background-image:` layers instead of separate `<img/>` elements?

Comment: I am confused about what you want to do. Is the image to have its full width or is it that you want the full width of the parent to show some of the image but with a bit of the images right hand side cut off?

Comment: I want the image to show a part of it and the part doesn't have a side cut off visible (full width)

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```css
.img_wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
.intro_sea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_wrap">
  <img class="intro_sea" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161357.png" alt="huh" />
  <img class="intro_sea" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161403.png" />
  <img class="intro_sea" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161409.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: No I want to crop the right side a little bit but it stays full width

Answer (score 0):

This works well:

```css
.intro_sea {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 150%;
  max-width: 170%;
  max-height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.intro_seadiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0099FF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro_seadiv">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161357.png" alt="huh" class="intro_sea">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161403.png" class="intro_sea">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duccweb/duccweb.github.io/main/media/Untitled10_20230407161409.png" class="intro_sea">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, why wouldn't you just use the "paint" app which is on the Microsoft computers (If you have one).

If you do not have a Microsoft computer or the above does not help you, you can try the above on a different app.

Hopefully that helps you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).